# Mysterious printer called "print". Where does it come from?

Tags: gnome, printing, ubuntu-gnome

When I want to print a document in Gnome 3.20 on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 I get the print dialog with my two installed printers to choose from. However, there's a third printer called "print" which doesn't do anything but "Getting printer information" or "Rejecting print". This "printer" does not show up in the printer settings where I have the two printers I have installed showing. I was wondering what this fake printer may be and if I can get rid of it somehow? See screenshot below of the print dialog.

[image: Printer dialog]

Comment: Open your printer manager (`system-config-printer`), and right-click on the mysterious "print" printer and chose "Properties". In the "Settings" tab, you should see the fields "Device URI" and "Make and model" which should contain useful information to determine what this device is. What do they contain?

Comment: It doesn't show in the print manager, only when I select print in applications like Gedit or Photos, so there's no way to remove it